# ListPlot multiple datasets over same x-values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Is there a better way to enter my data into a list plot?

```
ListPLot[{{{1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 4.3}, {2.9, 5.5}}, 
         {{1.1, 2.1}, {2.3, 4.6}, {2.9, 5.9}}, 
         {{1.1, 2}, {2.3, 4.8}, {2.9, 6.2}}}]
```

I think there should be a more efficient way, but cannot find it. I've read the documentation on `ListPlot` and `DataRange`.

Comment: By more efficient, I mean without typing the values of the independent variables more than once.  For large data sets, this would be a waste of time.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "independent" variable. What does you original data look like?

Comment: By “independent variables”, I meant the abscissa. I’m not sure about elsewhere, but in the U.S. that’s usually referred to as the independent variable or even simply $x$. I know I’ve had people from other countries ask me what I mean by $x$-axis when there was no $x$ defined in the question, but in the U.S. the values of the abscissa are usually referred to as the “independent variable” or simply $x$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
times = {1.1, 2.3, 2.9}; (* list of x values *)
states = {{2.2, 4.3, 5.5}, {2.1, 4.6, 5.9}, {2, 4.8, 6.2}}; (* lists of y values *)

td = TemporalData[states, {times}];
ListPlot[td, BaseStyle -> PointSize[.02], PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's terrific!  Thank you for introducing me to TemporalData.  That's exactly the type of functionality that I was hoping existed in Mathematica.

Comment: Joe, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know what those triangle did. I had no idea.

Answer (score 12):

A different approach, following J.W. Perry's structure,

```
ivar = {1.1, 2.3, 2.9};
dvars = {{2.2, 4.3, 5.5}, {2.1, 4.6, 5.9}, {2, 4.8, 6.2}}

data = Inner[List, ivar, #, List] & /@ dvars
```

Or, generalized (any number of dimensions),

```
data = MapThread[Flatten @* List, {ivar, #}] & /@ dvars
```

It might seem convoluted at first, but once you get acquainted with high level operators (Inner, Outer, MapThread...), "For" loops will look too verbose.

Comment: Does this work if the number of y values per x value are different for different x? If not, can it be generalized?

Answer (score 5):

If all what you want is to plot the data, then simply leave it as is, and use Show to combine the plots.

```
ivar = {1.1, 2.3, 2.9};
dvars = {{2.2, 4.3, 5.5}, {2.1, 4.6, 5.9}, {2, 4.8, 6.2}};
Show[ ListPlot[{ivar, #}] & /@ dvars ]
```

or to get more control of final layout, add more options to Show

```
Show[ListPlot[{ivar, #}] & /@ dvars, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Here I have assigned `ivar` to be your independent variables. You can add as many triplets as you want to `dvars` in this code and build the set `data`:

```
ivar = {1.1, 2.3, 2.9}; (*your independent variable values*)
dvars = {{2.2, 4.3, 5.5}, {2.1, 4.6, 5.9}, {2, 4.8, 6.2}}; (*dependent variables*)
data = {}; (*your data set*)
For[i = 1, i <= Length[dvars], i++,
 AppendTo[data, 
  Table[{ivar[[j]], dvars[[i]][[j]]}, {j, 1, Length[ivar]}]
  ]
 ]
```

You can view `data` of course, and you can produce your output with

```
ListPlot[data]
```

This will alleviate the repeated typing of `ivars` for your larger data set. Judicious modification of the `Length[ ]` function should make this code scalable for different tuple sets.

Comment: Thank you! Your programming skills far exceed mine. I was hoping mathematica had a built-in easy way to do it.